# Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox 5.0.10

Tags: 14.04

The Ubundu screen resolution 640*480 and not able to chnage.

I installed the virtual machine in windows 10

Comment: I am guessing that the Windows 10 is the host and Ubuntu is the guest.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Guest additions display Driver

open up a terminal and type in

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

and then reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer did help you, please don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)